# Problems with sending SMS message after upgrading to PHP 7.4

Tags: sms

I have installed Civi 5.51.1 over PHP7.2 and the send SMS function worked fine as it has for the past few years. However, the system complained about PHP 7.2 and said I should upgrade to PHP7.4.

After I upgraded to PHP7.4 everything seemed to be working EXCEPT send SMS action. When I try the browser just sticks with a progress indicator but never gets to the target page.

Any one else experienced this?

I am using Drupal 7.88 and Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: Which sms provider are you using?

Comment: It's ClickaTell